# Flink enrichment incoming data with processing time

Tags: apache-flink

in order to debug our application, we save all incoming data (s3 sink) in a separate part of the graph (even before the timestamping/watermarking process).
our data already includes timestamp (event timestamp), and before saving the data, we want to add one more field in which there will be a timestamp when the message actually got into the flink ( kind of processing time).

how best to do it? perhaps flink provides a special API for this
now we are doing very simple `new Date().getTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called *ingestion time*, btw. You are on your own to implement this; Flink doesn’t have anything built-in. What you’re doing seems fine.

Comment: looks like its available by using process function which have access to Context - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107932/apache-flink-how-to-get-timestamp-of-events-in-ingestion-time-mode

Comment: Support for ingestion-time timestamping was deprecated in Flink 1.10, which is why I didn't mention it.